# Rank of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(A_{ij})$ be a matrix of order $n$, where $A_{ij}= i+j$. Find the rank of $A$.

Comment: plz prove it in details

Comment: plz add your own thoughts on the problem to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The rank is 2. Show that the row space is spanned by $(2, 3, \cdots, n+1)$ and $(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$.